# How the React have better performance as compare with JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, reactjs

I am new in React js. Previously i used JSF framework for building the web application. According to my knowledge in JSF actually what does is, from the server side it will generate the html code for the corresponding JSF tag and send it to browser and display it. If you are using JSF 2 the corresponding front end html portion can replace through AJAX also.

I think the same thing we can done through React framework. In react JS you can generate the client side html code from server and it will render in frontend by using some Javascript Engine (Nashorn Javascript Engine).

So in both case the working is almost same (The response created from the server). Now a days everyone talks like the React JS is a high performance framework. So can anyone explain how it provide better performance?

I repeat i am new in React JS

Comment: Please read at least a little more detail on what both framworks are. Jsf = full mvc and on the wikipage of reactjs,  it states that it,  reactjs,  is only the v part

Comment: Why do you think it would be faster? You should try it and do some comparisons.

Comment: @WiredPrairie: He can't. It is not even like comparing apples and oranges, but apples and a seven course indonesian meal. (not one or the other is better, just soooooo different)

Comment: @Kukeltje - it's definitely comparable. You just have to decide what the metrics for success are. End user response time? Memory used in the browser? Number of users per server? Bandwidth used? Etc.

Comment: But than you are comparing reactjs + x + y + z with jsf,  not plain reactjs

Answer (score 2):

JSF is an MVC framework that takes advantage of server side rendering and makes use of many markup files.
React is a library for building graphical interfaces for applications according to the SPA (Single Page Application) model.
The strength of React lies in its ability to update the dom very quickly because it has a virtual one.
The final app can fit all in a single file.
As said React is only a library, it is not productive to use it alone to create an application.
(Similarly JSF is just a spec, without Rich Faces, Prime Faces, Omni Faces, Boots Faces and 3rd parts libraries it would be difficult to create an application)

In the SPA model, the session is stored with the user, the backend is just a set of services that are called up by the frontend.
There is a first authentication call which produces a token (JWT) which is stored on the client side and which will then be used to
invoke the server's (stateless) REST services. This is how the server can understand that it is the same user.
The key information for the session is stored on the client side, this fact already makes you understand that the server is relieved of the task of
keep in memory the sessions of all connected users.

In practice, when the user interacts on a SPA application, what travels is the data, not the markup since all or most of the markup is already on the client,
this implies a nice saving in data transfer. The REST paradigm uses json to structure the data to be exchanged with the client.
A json object (Javascript Object Notation) that arrives at the client is a string representing a Javascript object, The latter offers native functions
to convert Json strings to Javascript objects and vice versa. React has nothing more to do than use this object to "go there to that specific point" and update the displayed data
and it does it very quickly.

JSF requires the presence of its own and third-party Java libraries on the server side (configured as a part of an Application Server) so it requires configuration time
higher and has a rigid scalability compared to a React application ready for deployment which consists of only javscript files (even one would be enough)
which only needs a web server like Nginx to run. It is easy to understand how easily this last solution is scalable since the configuration is reduced to zero.
To scale, just create a nginx docker image with our React app inside and we are ready to move from the development pc to the various cloud solutions on the internet
ready to replicate our image across multiple on-demand instances.

Answer (score 2):

I believe performance all depends on the implementation, you can get both React and JSF to do the same thing.  JSF came before React, and React in my opinion adopted many concepts of JSF anyway.  React has not made any breakthrough that hasn't already been there with web templating engines since JSF 1.2.  JSF is a templating technology which React recreates with Javascript.

For a mobile device its better to get the complete HTML to save on battery initially... both React and JSF can do Single Page Apps (SPA) to use Ajax and update only a portion of the DOM while the User is interacting with the application.

For pages with user interaction, JSF will send the Javascript needed that will interact with one DOM directly, for React it will use its shadow DOM and the browser DOM.

Both can define custom UI components, JSF speedier sends the rendered HTML directly to the client, while React will have to build it using the client computer cpu.

We can compromise performance for faster UIs, changing UIs faster, software engineers vs scripting folks salary.  For any large scale, I'd prefer JSF because of reusable Java libraries in microservices, AI, Machine Learning, Android, and other things that has a JVM.  For the UI, maybe we can let a scripting person whip up a UI in React while we focus on the bigger solution?

Answer (score 1):

Internally, ReactJS uses a **virtual DOM** that will be "mapped" to the "real" DOM. In React you give your variables as `state` or `props` to the react component. React uses a special algorithm to detect changes in the components `state` or `props` and will only rerender the affected parts by synchronize the virtual with the "real" DOM.

Comment: And how is this an answer to the question?

Comment: Q: So can anyone explain how it provide better performance? A: Accessing the DOM is very slow. React uses a virtual DOM that is much faster.

Comment: **better** means comparing... in this case compared to JSF. JSF by itself does very little to NON dom manipulation... so it should be lightning fast (on the client). If you want more complex ui components  it depends on which components you use and how they manipulate the dom or not (PrimeFace components do little dom manipulation, only some small css things) so they are fast as well (on the client).

Comment: Oh and to be clear, I'm not against javascript ui frameworks, not at all.

Comment: React (and any other alike frameworks) renders the templates (aka HTML) client-side. In the client-side rendering strategy, the server only sends data bits (json) to the client -- instead of a whole HTML (from traditional architecture). That is usually faster than traditional server side rendering since:
 - you do less page reloads (due to the architecture)
 - some work is offloaded from the server
 - more data is cached (because the layout and the data are now separated, layouts can be separately cached)